# Python Unicode issues with .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

To make a long story short, I am writing a Python script that asks for the user to drop a .docx file and the file converts to .txt. Python looks for keywords within the .txt file and displays them to the shell. I was running into UnicodeDecodeError codec charmap etc..... I overcame that by writing within my for loop "word.decode("charmap"). NOW, Python is not displaying the keywords it does find to the shell. Any advice on how to overcome this? Maybe have Python skip through the characters it cannot decode and continue reading through the rest? Here is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import codecs

filename = input("Drag and drop resume here: ")
keywords =['NGA', 'DoD', 'Running', 'Programing', 'Enterprise', 'impossible', 'meets']
file_words = []

with open(filename, "rb") as file:
        for line in file:
            for word in line.split():
                word.decode("charmap")
                file_words.append(word)

comparison = []

for words in file_words:
    if words in keywords:
        comparison.append(words)

def remove_duplicates(comparison):
    output = []
    seen = set()
    for words in comparison:
        if words not in seen:
            output.append(words)
            seen.add(words)
    return output

comparison = remove_duplicates(comparison)
print ("Keywords found:",comparison)

key_count = 0
word_count = 0

for element in comparison:
    word_count += 1
for element in keywords:
    key_count += 1

Threshold = word_count / key_count

if Threshold <= 0.7:
    print ("The candidate is not qualified for")
else:
    print ("The candidate is qualified for")

file.close()
```

And the output:

```
Drag and drop resume here: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Resume_Newton Love_151111.txt
Keywords found: []
The candidate is not qualified for
```

Comment: Try this: `word.decode('utf-8',errors='ignore')`

Comment: Thanks, still does not output anything under keywords. I have read through this file myself and there are certainly key words in it that should be recognized by my program. It works for the other couple of files I've had it scan through. Maybe those non decodable characters interrupt the reading process?

Comment: Why are you passing `"charmap"` to `decode`? Can you provide a small sample of text that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Here is a sample:                        ÐÏà¡±á                >  þÿ                Š                þÿÿÿ    ˆ   ‰   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

Comment: How can I tell Python to filter these characters?

Comment: That's not a text file.  You **do** know that .docx is a binary .zip format of .xml files, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. Here is my code, but I tried a docx file that seemed to be more complex and when converted to .txt the entire file consisted of special characters. So now I am thinking that I should go to the python-docx module, since it deals with xml files like Word documents. I added "encoding = 'charmap'"

```
with open(filename, encoding = 'charmap') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            file_words.append(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, don't open text files in binary mode.  The default is the file will decode to Unicode using `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` (`cp1252` on US Windows):

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            file_words.append(word)
```

or specify an encoding:

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf8') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            file_words.append(word)
```

You *do* need to know the encoding of your file.  There are other options to `open` as well, including `errors='ignore'` or `errors='replace'` but you shouldn't get errors if you know the correct encoding.

As others have said, posting a sample of your text file that reproduces the error and the error traceback would help diagnose your specific issue.

Comment: When I use "charmap" and "ISO-8859-1" they don't give any errors, but yet Python discontinues reading the file. Using "utf-8" gives me errors. Here is the sample I provided in one of the earlier comments:                                                                                                    ÐÏà¡±á                >  þÿ                Š                þÿÿÿ    ˆ   ‰   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

Comment: @E_R, that's not an encoded text file.  Why do you think you can decode it?  some code page decodings like ISO-8859-1 translate the 256 possible bytes into 256 possible Unicode characters.  It will never fail to convert, but if the file wasn't in ISO-8859-1-encoded format to begin with you just get garbage.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone cares. It's been a long time, but wanted to clear up that I didn't even know the difference between binary and txt files back in these days. I eventually found a doc/docx module for python that made things easier. Sorry for the headache!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32073293)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe posting the code producing the traceback would be easier to fix.

I'm not sure this is the only problem, maybe this would work better:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            file_words.append(word.decode("charmap"))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ResumeScan.py", line 12, in <module>
    file_words.append(word.decode("charmap"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: I don't think Python 3.5.1 takes "decode()" as Python 2.7 does

Comment: words.decode(encoding='UTF-8', errors='strict') # assuming UTF-8 NFC input

Comment: ahah indeed there is no `decode()` in Python 3...
try: except: might suit your decode issues